# Money::Bank::GoogleCurrencyFetchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use the "exchange_to (: CLP) .to_i" method, it gives me the error Money :: Bank :: GoogleCurrencyFetchError in OrdersController#create
Money :: Bank :: GoogleCurrencyFetchError

```
# class OrdersController < ApplicationController
def create
    @buying_methods = Order.buying_methods.keys
    @shipping_type_clients = Order.shipping_type_clients.keys
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.dollar = Money.new(100, "USD").exchange_to(:CLP).to_i
    @order.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        if @order.cmm_buy?
          @order.in_draft!
        end
        format.html { redirect_to "#{my_account_path}#my-orders", notice: 'El pedido se ha creado con éxito.' }
      else
        @order.products.build
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

# config/initializers/google_currency.rb
require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'

# seconds after than the current rates are automatically expired (24 hours)
Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400

# set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
Money.default_bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new 

# config/initializers/
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.register_currency = {
    :iso_code            => "US8",
    :subunit_to_unit     => 100_000_000,
    :thousands_separator => ".",
    :decimal_mark        => ","
  }
end
```

Comment: There is something wrong with GoogleCurrency today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your file:

> config/initializer/money.rb

add this line on top:

```
Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency::SERVICE_HOST="finance.google.com"
```

Comment: This is quick solution but upgrade it to 3.4.0 will solve problem

Answer (score 3):

We have the same issue unfortunately.. have [reported](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency/issues/59) and waiting for a response.

Looks like there's a [new version](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency/pull/56) of `google_currency` that might address the issue.

Comment: Upgrade the gem a 3.4.0